# Can nonnegative functions $f(x,y,z)$ be written as a product of pairwise functions $u(x,y) v(y,z) w(x, z)$?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, factorization, ising-model

In my course on probabilistic graphical models, my professor made a claim which I find a little sus. In discussing the equivalence between Markov Random Fields and Factor Graphs, the following example was given:

An MRF over 3 variables was drawn as a triangle graph (3-cycle). This admits density function like $\psi(x, y, z)$. Naturally, an equivalent factor graph can be drawn by having only one factor connected to all three variables, $p(x,y,z) \propto f(x, y, z)$. However the example where a factor graph with three factors, one along each edge, was also considered, which admits a density like $p(x,y,z) \propto f_1(x,y) \cdot f_2(y,z) \cdot f_3(x,z)$.

The question was posed that all three graphical models are equivalent for the appropriate choice of factors. Formally, the claim is as follows:

> For any nonnegative function $f(x,y,z)$, there exists nonnegative functions $u, v, w$ such that $f(x,y,z)=u(x,y)\cdot v(y,z)\cdot w(x,z)$. We can assume that $x,y,z \in \{0,1\}$.

My guess at a counterexample would be a function along the lines of $f(x,y,z) = xy + yz + xz$, but I'm stuck at finding a way to *prove* that this cannot be written as a product of pairwise factors.

Intuitively, for a binary alphabet, $f(x,y,z)$ can be encoded using 8 values, where each of $u,v,w$ need 4 values, leaving 8 degrees of freedom versus 12. But this intuition seems weak to me.

Comment: Take $\log$ of every function. Then you are looking for a representation of the form $f(x,y,z)=u(x,y)+v(y,z)+w(x,z)$. This looks like a simple linear algebra problem then.

Comment: That said, $x,y,z\in \{0,1\}$ is essential because the claim is obviously false for $x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @PeterKravchuk, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439794/can-nonnegative-functions-fx-y-z-be-written-as-a-product-of-pairwise-functio#comment1134375_439794), one has to be a little careful with the linear algebra, since the log-ified functions might take the value $-\infty$.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, then your example $f(x, y, z) = x y + y z + x z$ can be achieved on $\{0, 1\}^3$ with each of $u$, $v$, and $w$ vanishing at $(0, 0)$, $v(1, 1) = 3$, $w(0, 1) = 1/3$, and $u$, $v$, and $w$ being otherwise $1$.

Comment: Not exactly what is asked but somewhat relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Arnold_representation_theorem

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ for $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$. The only zero of $f$ is $(0,0,0)$.

If we had three functions $u,v,w$ such that $f(x,y,z)=u(x,y)v(y,z)w(z,x)$ for every $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$, at least one of the functions $u,v,w$ would vanish at $(0,0)$, so $f$ would vanish on a whole line.

This argument also works on $\{0,1\}^3$.

Comment: Thanks! This is a really cute counterexample!

Answer (score 11):

This is not true. If $f(x,y,z)$ has such a factorization, then

$$f(a,a,a) f(a,b,b) f(b,a,b) f(b,b,a) = f(b,b,b) f(b,a,a) f(a,b,a) f(a,a,b).$$

A generic three-input function won't obey this.

---

Your intuition about $8$ versus $12$ parameters is a good place to start. Indeed, if you switch from binary inputs to $n$-ary inputs, then you have $n^3$ versus $3 n^2$, so you have to fail once $n^3 > 3 n^2$, in other words $n>3$.

For $n=2$, looking at dimensions makes it seem likely such a representation exists, but the dimensionality isn't enough to resolve the issue. Switching to $\log$-coordinates, you have a linear map $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^{12} \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^{8}$ and you want to know if it is surjective. When you write out the actual linear map, it turns out to be only rank $7$; the equation above is the equation of the image (put back in multiplicative coordinates).

Comment: And more generally, a necessary condition is $$f(a,b,c)f(a,b',c')f(a',b,c')f(a',b',c)=f(a',b,c)f(a,b',c)f(a,b,c')f(a',b',c')$$ for every real numbers $a,b,c,a',b',c'$.

Comment: Wouldn't multiplicative coördinates give you a map $\mathbb R_{\ge 0}^{12} \to \mathbb R_{\ge 0}^8$, and log coördinates give you a map $(\mathbb R \cup \{-\infty\})^{12} \to (\mathbb R \cup \{-\infty\})^8$ (which restricts to a linear map $\mathbb R^{12} \to \mathbb R^8$)?

Answer (score 2):

A simple counterexample is the function $\exp{xyz}$.  This follows from the criterion given below since the appropriate third derivative of its logarithm $xyz$ is $1$.

As noted already, you can use logarithms to reduce to the corresponding problem for sums.  But if $f$ has such a representation, then $$\frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial x \partial y \partial z}=0.$$

Per request: the following discrete version is also a necessary condition:
$$f(x_0,y_0,z_0)-f(x_1,y_0,z_0)-f(x_0,y_1,z_0)-f(x_0,y_0,z_1)+f(x_0,y_1,z_1)+f(x_1,y_0,z_1)+f(x_1,y_1,z_0)-f(x_1,y_1,z_1)=0$$ for any choices of the variables.

Both of these equations can be transformed into suitable ones for the the original problem by applying them to $\log f$.

In fact, a quick computation suggests that these necessary conditions are also sufficient but this should be regarded as conjectural—I haven't sat down to write out proofs.

Comment: This argument should be discretized (replacing the derivatives with rates of variations) to work with non differentiable functions.